# I have a Facebook app running in a Page Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://apps.facebook.com/invite-sweup
I have a Facebook app running in a Page Tab (the tab of a Facebook Page for an organization). The Page Tab URL (and Secure Page Tab URL) points to a URL on my own server which holds a PHP page that contains an iframe of a Google Calendar.

The app works perfectly fine when I open the Page using the admin account (both http and https). But when I open the Page using the user account of someone who has 'Liked' the Page, the app does not appear at all (both http and https). Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Is the app live, or still in development mode?

Comment: Is an application to invite friends for my blog
I do the application from here
http://www.bloggerbuster.com/2012/07/add-facebook-invite-friends-link-to.html

Comment: Yes, but if the app is in development mode, only the admins can see it - check the app settings

Comment: Yes, how can I end the status of development for all to see... Can you help me in the steps because I am a beginner

Comment: It's on the Status & Review tab - there's a big switch at the top showing if the app is public which allows you to change it - if it won't allow you to change it to public, there should be a message or tooltip explaining why

Comment: Did you mean that he will remain in the state of development? But I did not understand how to make it in general..
Knowing you, I make it General on the Status & Review tab.

Comment: Can you help me directly, I'm going to make you an administrator
Addme fb.com/abdallhadagga 
I'll be grateful to you